# Applying color to a OpenGL ES 2.0 Point Sprite texture in Fragment shader?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, particle-system

I am creating a particle emitter with a texture that is a white circle with alpha. Unable to color the sprites using color passed to the fragment shader.

I tried the following:

```
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Sampler, gl_PointCoord) * colorVarying;
```

This seems to be doing some kind of additive coloring.

What I am attempting is porting this:
http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/source-code-particle-based-explosions-in-iphone-opengl-es/
from ES 1.1 to ES 2.0

Comment: I verified Dirk's answer to be correct. Thanks, Dirk. My particle emitter still doesn't work though! Anyone else want to download the code in the link and tweak it to make it work with ES2.0, let me know the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your code, consider the following example:

- texture2D = (1,0,0,1) = red - fully opaque
- colorVarying = (0,1,0,0.5) = green - half transparent

then gl_FragColor would be (0,0,0,0.5) black - half transparent.

Generally, you can use [mix](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/mix.xml) to interpolate values, but if I understood your problem then its even easier.

Basically, you only want the alpha channel from your texture and apply it to another color, right? then you could do this:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(colorVarying.rgb, texture2D(Sampler, gl_PointCoord).a)
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped with adding alpha to the particles.. They still appear white though. Could it be to do with my blend function:  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);

Comment: I don't know. The default for blending is usually glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)